# how to put a string value from <h:inputHidden> to a bean property?

Tags: jsf, tomcat, input, primefaces, javabeans

I have a simple "register" page built with primefaces tags where user inputs his login, clicks OK and that info is stored in DB via POST request to a bean. Login is saved properly, but there is another one...
I want to store implicit String field which represents user's "role" and is always equal to "Guest". I've tried two different approaches but all of them failed for me:

1)

```
<h:outputLabel for="login" value="Login" />
<p:inputText required="true" id="login" value="#{userBean.login}" 
    label="Login" />
<h:inputHidden value="#{userBean.roleName}" id="rolename" 
    name="Guest" />
<p:commandButton value="OK" update="dataForm" action="#{userBean.create}" 
     ajax="false">
```

2)

```
<h:outputLabel for="login" value="Login" />
<p:inputText required="true" id="login" value="#{userBean.login}"
     label="Login" />
<p:commandButton value="OK" update="dataForm" action="#{userBean.create}" 
    ajax="false">
    <f:param id="rolename" value="User" binding="#{userBean.roleName}"/> 
</p:commandButton>
```

could anybody provide an idea for me?
thx.
environment: jdk7, tomcat7, eclipse, primefaces

Comment: In case it's always 'Guest', why don't you want to keep it solely in bean? Moreover, why are you going to keep user role on the client this way? But if you insist that it is a right way, you can always update its hidden value with JavaScript and it will end up in your bean (number 1 try). By the way, omit `name` attribute as it's designed for other purposes.

Comment: @skuntsel, well the point is that the same "registering page" is used by both guests and admins. So when admin use it to register manually a new user, then he chooses role name from dropdown menu, but when "guest" as new user registers himself, then dropdown menu is disabled with proper tag, so it's value isn't passed with POST...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either plain HTML `<input type="hidden">` or JSF `<f:param>` along with a `@ManagedProperty`.

So, either

```
<input type="hidden" name="rolename" value="Guest" />
```

or

```
<p:commandButton ...>
    <f:param name="rolename" value="Guest" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Either way, they're available as a HTTP request parameter by

```
@ManagedProperty("#{param.rolename}")
private String rolename; // +getter+setter
```